# SageMaker experiment tracking duplication

Tags: python, machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-experiments

I am trying to train a model using script mode via AWS SageMaker.
I would like to track this training job with AWS SageMaker Experiments together with some calculated metrics in the training job. When I start the training job a new experiment run is created successfully that tracks all the provided hyperparameters (e.g., nestimators).

However, as said earlier, additionally, I also want to track other metrics (e.g., Accuracy) in the custom script. Here I use `load_run()` before I fit the model and then for example log a metric with `run.log_metric()`. However, when I do that, SageMaker creates a new **separate** experiment entry in the UI which means that my hyperparameters and metrics are stored **separately** in two individual experiment runs:

[image: Two separate runs created by SageMaker]

I would like to see the metrics and hyperparameters all in one Experiment run combined. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the abbreviated code I am using to kick off the training process:

```
exp_name = "sklearn-script-mode-experiment"

with Run(
    experiment_name=exp_name,
    sagemaker_session=sess,
) as run:

    sklearn_estimator = SKLearn('train.py',
                                    instance_type='ml.m5.large',
                                    framework_version='1.0-1',
                                    role="arn:aws:iam:::role/service-role/AmazonSageMaker-ExecutionRole-",
                                    hyperparameters={'nestimators': 100},
                                    environment={"REGION": REGION})

    sklearn_estimator.fit({'train': f's3://{BUCKET}/{S3_INPUT_PATH}'})
```

Here is the abbreviated `train.py`:

```
    #parsing arguments here ... etc ...


    model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=args.nestimators,
                                   max_depth=5,
                                   random_state=1)

    with load_run(sagemaker_session=sagemaker_session) as run:

        model.fit(X, y)

        run.log_metric(name = "Final Test Loss", value = 0.9)
```

Comment: [The bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76821347/timeline) attracted a [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) plagiariser.

Comment: Note: ChatGPT (or similar) repeated the misspelling "Sagemaker" from the question even though it knew it to be "SageMaker" (non-leading question *"AWS: Is it "SageMaker" or "Sagemaker"?"*). Thus non-perfect spelling is ***not*** a contraindication.